# Erro encoding PHP função copy()

Tags: php

Estou com um problema que até o momento não consegui resolver. Quando utilizo a função `copy()` do php, o arquivo que é copiado de determinado lugar para o outro faz com que arquivos que possuam acentuação fiquem descaracterizados quanto ao seu nome.

**Estou utilizando IIS 10 no Windows 10 E PHP 5.3.9.**

```
copy(string $source , string $dest);
```

Já printei o  `$dest` e os nomes saem corretamente, porém quando a função é executada vou verificar na pasta destino o arquivo está com seu nome todo descaracterizado conforme nome abaixo de um arquivo XML que o nome correto seria `Padrão José e Porâ.xml` (estou utilizando estas acentuações para fins de testes.)

`PadrÃ£o_josÃ©_e_porÃ¢.xml` *(Nome errado do arquivo)*

Sei que a função `copy()` possuí um terceiro parâmetro para `stream_context_create()` porém não consegui achar exemplos da utilização deste parâmetro para ser  usado localmente.

O erro acontece depois que a **função é executada**, ou seja, o arquivo que é copiado de um lugar para outro fica com acentuação descaracterizada, o motivo eu não sei pois passo o nome correto na variável `$dest`.

Também já adicionei `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` no arquivo PHP.

Alguma opinião?

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá @bacco esta resposta sugerida por você não condiz com o problema que possuo, estou com problema com a função copy() do php como comentado no texto que redigi e não apenas em codificação em si. O erro está sendo gerado depois que a função é executada!

Comment: Na verdade o problema tem grande chance de ser o mesmo (não em relação ao encoding da saída, mas em relação a conversão indevida). O que precisa é localizar no código qual dos subsistemas está fazendo a conversão indevida. Se puder por os trechos do código que manipulam e capturam o nome do arquivo, podemos analisar melhor. Lembre-se que toda publicação, mesmo fechada, é passível de revisão (e até reabertura se de fato for um problema diferente). Mas para isto, se [edit] e puser o código relevante, fica mais fácil de ajudarmos (seja reabrindo, ou orientando a como aplicar a solução).

Comment: Para maior chance de solução, seria bom por todos os trechos que manipulam $source e $dest. A idéia aqui é você conseguir ter o problema resolvido, de qq forma. Só precisamos de mais material pra analisar.

Answer (score -2):

Cria um arquivo **.htaccess** e adiciona o seguinte código: ***AddDefaultCharset utf-8***